# Increase MAC-Address by 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to increment a hexadecimal number (MAC-Address) by 1.

For example, I have a MAC-Address in such format:

```
00:A1:2C:3B:99:1F
```

And I need to increase this value by 1 and save the new value in the same format:

```
00:A1:2C:3B:99:20
```

Query:

```
UPDATE Info
SET MAC = HEXTORAW(TO_CHAR(
                     TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(RAWTOHEX(MAC), 1, 20), RPAD('x', 20, 'x')) + 1,
                     RPAD('fm0', 22, 'X')
                )
                || SUBSTR(RAWTOHEX(MAC), 21))
WHERE ID = '';
```

Comment: Having that example MAC-address, what's the value after adding 1 to it?

Comment: Do you use Oracle or MySQL? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: The value after adding 1 is: 00:A1:2C:3B:99:20. I use Oracle...

Comment: What if the mac-address ends with :FF?

Comment: In my case, mac-address do not end with :FF....

Comment: Look at my query below. For MAC ending with `FF` it is replacing it with `100`. You can always put a check if you dont want it to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Updated the update statement to handle single digit mac address

This will work but the case where it ends with `:FF`, it will not work.

```
            create table test_utsav_mac(id integer,mac varchar2(20));

            insert into test_utsav_mac
            values
            (1,'01:26:5b:61:54:c0');

        UPDATE TEST_UTSAV_MAC
        SET MAC=  CASE WHEN LENGTH(LTRIM(TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR(MAC,16,2) , 'xx' )+1,'xxxx'))) = 1
        THEN SUBSTR(MAC,1,15) || '0' || LTRIM(TO_CHAR( TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR(MAC,16,2) , 'xx' )+1, 'xxxx' ))
        ELSE SUBSTR(MAC,1,15) || LTRIM(TO_CHAR( TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR(MAC,16,2) , 'xx' )+1, 'xxxx' ))
        END
        WHERE ID = 1

            select * from test_utsav_mac;
```

Output

```
ID   MAC
1   01:26:5b:61:54:c1
```

What `substr(mac,1,15) || ltrim(to_char( to_number( substr(mac,16,2) , 'xx' )+1, 'xxxx' ))` is doing is

- `ltrim(to_char( to_number( substr(mac,16,2) , 'xx' )+1, 'xxxx' ))` is
  converting last hex value to decimal and increment by 1.
- Then I am converting it back to hex and trimming.
- Then concatenate the rest of
  the string back to this result.

PS: If you want to handle `:FF` logic in it, then put it in a PL/SQL block and let it throw an exception in that case.

Comment: See if you can find a way to append a `0` before `1` before concatenation. Else I would take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Ustav can you take a look, how is possible to append a 0 before 1 in the case to handle :00 logic?

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check.